# two spinners in one activity in android

Tags: android

In my activity i have two spinners, depending on one spinner the second spinner should change. Like if I select fruits in first spinner then second spinners should have drop down list as apple,mango etc. But after selecting the items in both the spinners i should get the output in the edit text at the down of the layout. I have done coding for both, and its is working the problem is that when i am selecting the item 4 in the second spinner, that 4th item is not getting displayed instead it is showing only first option. I have created array in string.file.

```
     package com.example.first;

                       import java.lang.reflect.Array;

                import android.app.Activity;

              import android.os.Bundle;

   import android.view.Display;
      import android.view.View;

      import android.widget.AdapterView;
     import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

    import android.widget.Spinner;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

     Spinner s1, s2;
    // TextView t1;
     EditText ed;

     @Override

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

      s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
      ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


     s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
     }

     @Override

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,

       long arg3) {

      parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
      switch (pos) {
    case 0:
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
       R.array.Ismail,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);                 
    // s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
       s2.setAdapter(adapter);
    break;

    case 1:
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
      R.array.abdul,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       s2.setAdapter(adapter1);

       break;

    case 2:
     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,    
     R.array.Mohammed,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       s2.setAdapter(adapter2);

       break;
     }


      Object result=s1.getSelectedItem();

      Object result2=s2.getSelectedItem();
      ed.setText(""+result +":"+result2);

      }

      @Override

      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

      }

     }
```

Comment: Why is the `setOnItemSelectedListener` for `s2` commented?

Comment: @Pratik i have created array in string.xml file

Comment: @Apoorv that i have tried for displaying teh spinner, but when i am writing there is only one dropdown list for all the items in the first spinner

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
//  first create string variables to store selected spinner item values and Id values
// First list model has two things, 1.Name and 2.FirstItemId
// Second list model had three things, 1.Name 2.Id and 3.FirstItemId

String st_firstSpinnerSelectedItem, st_secondSpinnerSelectedItem,st_firstSpinnerSelectedItemID,st_secondSpinnerSelectedItemID;

ArrayList<FirstListModel> firstList=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<SecondListMode> secondList = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spnFirst:
            st_firstSpinnerSelectedItem = firstList.get(position).getName();
            st_firstSpinnerSelectedItemID = firstList.get(position).getFirstItemId();
            setSecondSpinner(st_firstSpinnerSelectedItemID);
            break;
        case R.id.spnSecond:
            st_secondSpinnerSelectedItem = secondList.get(position).getName();
            st_secondSpinnerSelectedItemID = secondList.get(position).getId();
            break;
    }

}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

// write below code out side of the onCreate()
 private void setSecondSpinner(String st_firstSpinnerSelectedItemID) {

    ArrayList<SecondListModel> selectedSecondListItems = new ArrayList<SecondListModel>();
    for (int i=0; i<secondList.size();i++){
        String secondSpinnerItemId = secondList.get(i).getFirstItemId();
        if (secondSpinnerItemId .equals(st_firstSpinnerSelectedItemID)){
            selectedSecondListItems .add(secondList.get(i));
        }
    }
    SecondSpinAdapter secondAd = new SecondSpinAdapter(context, selectedSecondListItems );
    spnSecond.setAdapter(seconddAd );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Helper.country);
        country.setAdapter(ad);
        country.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Value_spinner1 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                state.setEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "" + parent.getItemAtPosition(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                switch (Value_spinner1) {
                case "INDIA":
                    india_state();
                    break;
                case "pak":
                    pak_state();
                    break;
                case "Sri Lanka":
                    sri_lanka_state();
                    break;

                default:
                    // state.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        state.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Value_spinner2 = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ed.setText(Value_spinner1 + Value_spinner2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    public void sri_lanka_state() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<String> state_spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Helper.Sri_Lanka_State);
        state.setAdapter(state_spinner);

    }

    public void pak_state() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayAdapter<String> state_spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Helper.pak_state);
        state.setAdapter(state_spinner);
    }

    public void india_state() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayAdapter<String> state_spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Helper.INDIA_STATE);
        state.setAdapter(state_spinner);
    }
```

Comment: just try like this and if any problem then let me know